# Why does my Test Site suddenly have a toolbar with search at the top?

Tags: community, force.com-sites

Update: The global header removal on the profile system permissions helped part of it, but there is still a portion of the header that contains the "search" bar and the dark grey, now with a blue bubble of the users name with a dropdown for "my settings" and "logout". Need it to have no toolbar and just be the page

how it looks now...

[image]

---

My Sandbox version of my site looked just like prod in virtually every way until, ironically, we did a sandbox refresh. I don't understand why things would deviate during a process that makes it identical, but no matter, that's what happened.

Here is what it looks like in Prod (and used to look like in Test)
[image: Production]

And, since the sandbox refresh, now we can see it looks like this.

[image]

You may notice it looks like when you're logged into your org. Pulling the dropdown does in fact reveal "My Settings" "Edit Contact Info" and "Logout", and the search allows me to search the org as if I'm just logged in. Very strange, and a bit concerning for upcoming deployments in case that changes things.

I need to actually test something with my regular logout (visible in the first screenshot of Prod) and I of course cannot, since it looks like this in Test.

Thoughts?

Comment: Update: The header removal helped part of it, but there is still a portion of the header that contains the "search" bar and the dark grey, now with a blue bubble of the users name with a dropdown for "my settings" and "logout". Need it to have *no* toolbar and just be the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when this changed, perhaps sandbox refresh did this for some reason, but in community branding it reset my header from my custom one to what I am guessing is a default one.

Answer (score -2):

I believe this pops up when you activate communities.

Reference:

- [Enable the Global Header for Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable_global_header.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi there. That doesn't quite make sense to me. If that were the case, wouldn't it look that way in Prod rather than Test? Also, how do I get it to go away and actually represent Production?

Comment: Checkout the documentation I just added. That should help.

Comment: It looks like this is describing how to change permission sets to show this. This user has no permission sets, and it's visible. I would like a little more explanation if possible - nothing that I can understand actually changed, and all of a sudden it looks this way *in test* and not prod, with no permission sets on this user. How do I remove it?

Comment: Oh oh, my bad, I was looking at permission sets, not sys. permissions on profile. Think I got it.

Comment: And...."nothing changed" might have actually been our other admin and didn't tell me. I think I can close this out hah. Thanks!